# How to optionally pass argument to subprocess?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, python-requests

I'm getting some entry using `tkinter` to use as arguments on subprocess and would like to make some of these arguments optionally for working.

How can I do it? I really stack on this condition.

```
def start(self):
    firstarg = ("--firstarg ", self.firstarg_entry.get())
    secondarg =   ("--secondarg ", self.secondarg_entry.get())
    subprocess.call([self.Tipvar.get(), 'mytool.py', firstarg, secondarg], shell = True)
```

Comment: You don't want to pass argument if value is empty?

Comment: Python's `argparse` allows you to setup args while allowing for optional params: https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html

Comment: You can use `filter()` with unpacking: `subprocess.call([self.Tipvar.get(), 'mytool.py', *filter(lambda x: bool(x[1]) ,(firstarg, secondarg))], shell = True)`.

Comment: @OlvinRoght Yes, its! Thanks for replying

Do you think that filter() will work with the structure above or must i change anything?

Because how you can see value are not completely empty because i concatenate "--firstarg " before taken value from entry to declare it.

Comment: @barroso, that's why i passed `lambda` which check only second item of tuple. You can use also generator with unpacking `subprocess.call([self.Tipvar.get(), 'mytool.py', *(i for i in (a, b) if i[1])], shell = True)`.

Comment: Unless you are *specifically* asking about how to solve a cross-version compatibility problem (in which case your question should obviously describe that problem) you should not mix the [tag:python-2.7] and [tag:python-3.x] tags. I have edited to remove them both; you might want to add back one or the other, but we don't know which. The expectation in 2020 will certainly be that you are using Python 3.

Comment: Hey @OlvinRoght that works for me thanks!

subprocess.call([self.Tipvar.get(), 'mytool.py', *filter(lambda x: bool(x[1]) ,(firstarg, secondarg))],) 

also removed shell = True as someone advise!

You guys know how can i send CTRL C keys to stop this open subprocess?

Comment: @barroso, you should use [`subprocess.Popen()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen) so you would have possibility to use [`Popen.terminate()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.terminate). Btw, while you choose first option I advised and it works well, second *(with generator)* should be sightly faster.

Comment: @OlvinRoght thanks for your time man!
i changed .call to .Popen

so defined:

    def stop(self):
        subprocess.Popen.terminate()
        print ("Tool stoped")

and create this one:

        ### Creating Button Stop
        self.bt_stop = Button(self.frame_1, text='Stop' , bg = '#b8200f',
                                fg = 'white', command= self.stop)
        self.bt_stop.place(relx=0.47, rely=0.08, relwidth=0.1, relheight=0.14)
and got a Traceback 
TypeError: terminate() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

Comment: @barroso, `Popen()` returns object, you should call `terminate()` on this object. Like this: `obj = subprocess.Popen(...)` and `obj.terminate()`.

Comment: @OlvinRoght, im trying the function
`def stop(self):
        subprocess.Popen.terminate()
        print ("Tool stopped on terinal")`

the button to stop 

       `### Creating Button Stop
        self.bt_stop = Button(self.frame_1, text='Stop' , bg = '#b8200f',
                                fg = 'white', command= self.stop)
        self.bt_stop.place(relx=0.47, rely=0.08, relwidth=0.1, relheight=0.14)`


to start using code mentioned on topic.

Thanks

Comment: You shouldn't use `subprocess.Popen.terminate()`, you should call `terminate()` on `Popen` object which have been returned from `subprocess.Popen()`.

Comment: @OlvinRoght thanks for your time, i didnt got it! I m sorry.
Could you please show me an example ? How you make it using that 2 functions?

Comment: @barroso, you need to use global variable or any other container which could be accessible from both functions and store there result of `subprocess.Popen()`.

Comment: @OlvinRoght thanks brother. if i make it global using for exemple:
`obj = subprocess.Popen(...)`

how can i call it inside
`def start(self):
obj()`
`def stop(self):
obj.terminate()`

Is it?

Comment: @barroso, you can use [`global`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-global-statement) statement inside `start()`.

Comment: @OlvinRoght, brother, thank you a lot!!!!! You pro! Thanks for you time and patience! Have a very nice weekend!

Comment: @barroso, have you achieved desired result?

Comment: @OlvinRoght, Yes man, following your steps / tips i achieved desired result!

Thank you a lot!

Comment: @OlvinRoght do you know why I can’t use it on Linux? Getting TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not tuple